# Permutation of a word with atleast one of the alphabet in it

Tags: combinatorics

> How many possible words do I have if I have: k-different Alphabet with
>   the length n and atleast one of every element from the alphabet is in
>   the word.

**My attempt**

For example I got an k-long alphabet = {a, b, c} and the length n = 5. I am creating n - k extra variables x and y. x and y can be every element from the alphabet. What I have to calculate first is the permutation of the set {a, b, c, x, y}. Now I have to multiply it by a certain variable so I can also get the permutation of x and y.

**My question**

What do I have to multiply it with after calculating the permutation first?

I already look into the striling number and the inclusion-exclusion principle. Do I have to use them to get the answer? I dont see any points use it.

Comment: The problem is that depending on the values of $x$ and $y$, two permutations can represent the same word, e.g. $abcxy$ = $abcab$ for $x=a$ and $y = b$ and $abcyx$ = $abcab$ for $x=b$ and $y=a$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For $i=1,\ldots,k$, let $A_i$ be the set of words that do not have the $i^{th}$ letter. The universal set of all words has cardinality $k^n$. Use inclusion-exclusion to find the value you require, which is:

$$\bigcap_{i=1}^{k}A_i^c.$$